# How to keep searching for a matching player and then stop the search in the Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have 2 questions.I want to make a firebase chatroulette clone app which people can randomly matchs and chat with each other.In app i have 3 status waiting,searching people and chatting with person.First question is how can i always check the status of people every second?.Second question is how can i keep searching until there is an user with status "searching".

```
public void Search(){
     count = 0;

     user_dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                 User user2 = dataSnapshot1.getValue(User.class);
                 Log.i("ID-",user2.getUser_id());
                 if(user2.getStatus()=="searching"){

                     user.setStatus("chatting");
                     progressDialog.cancel();
                     user_dbref.child(user2.getUser_id()).child("status").setValue("chatting");
                     user_dbref.child(user.getUser_id()).child("status").setValue("chatting");
                 }
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can i always check the status of people every second?

There is no need to repeatedly poll. When you call `addValueEventListener`, Firebase will actively keep monitoring the results of that reference or query. If anything changes, it will inform you straight away by a call to `onDataChange` with the updated data for the query/location.

> how can i keep searching until there is an user with status "searching"?

Your current code already keeps listening for the data in `user_dbref` until you tell it to stop. Once you find a match, just call `removeEventListener` with a reference to the listener.

A simple way to do this:

```
final ValueEventListener listener = user_dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
             ...
             if(user2.getStatus()=="searching"){
                 ...

                 user_dbref.removeEventListener(listener);
             }
         }
```

Comment: when i make user_dbref.removeEventListener(listener) all code be like different :D

Comment: I don't understand what that means. Can you clarify?